# Tem como eu fazer esse script redirecionar para uma pagina de obrigado e depois para o whats?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, widget

Olá, sou novo em javascript, estou usando um site chamado Whatshelp para me gerar um botao do whats, eu precisaria que quando a pessoa clicasse no botao do whats ele redirecionasse para uma pagina de obrigado e logo em seguida fosse para o whatsapp.Se algu

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            whatsapp: "5547984062427", // WhatsApp number
            call_to_action: "Fale Conosco!", // Call to action
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: você não deveria fazer isso na página de obrigado?

Comment: Infelizmente foi pedido que o botao redirecionasse para a pagina de obrigado e logo depois pra pro whats.